# Decreasing column size has never changed the table size. PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

Some time ago I read about resizing a column in PostgreSQL updating the atttypmod manually.

https://web.archive.org/web/20111007112138/http://sniptools.com/databases/resize-a-column-in-a-postgresql-table-without-changing-data

It works properly, however, although I re-size a 2500 character column to 250, table size has never changed. Should I run a vacumm? What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you quote should be taken down, as this advice is dangerous and misleading. This will *not* change the size of existing columns. It is not supported to modify catalog tables directly, for the reason that it is too easy to get data corruption, which is what I would call a `varchar(250)` column with 1000 characters in it.

You should change the data type by properly rewriting the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col
   TYPE varchar(250) USING substr(col, 1, 250);
```